# Visual Studio 2015 Immediate Window has no code completion in Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms PCL project (Droid,iOS) I have no intellisense in the immediate window. Hope someone can give me a hint to fix that. 
Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Have you tried building the project once? You won't get intellisense for XAML Forms projects until it has been built once. The same holds true for the Xamarin.Forms previewer.

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding. I don't have intellisense in the immediate window while debugging. For instance I have a DateTime var x and want to evaluate I enter : ?x.   but no members are displayed even when I hit Ctrl + Space